# Using Go to copy from one postgres db to another

Tags: postgresql, go, copy, etl

I'd like to use Go to copy postgres data from database A, view A into Database B, table B.  This will be done for several dozen tables and I'd like to take advantage of the concurrency offered by Go.

I can do this using psql commandline that looks something like:

```
psql -h hostServer -p 5432 -U dbUser -d dbName \
    -c "\copy (Select * From myView) TO STDOUT" \
    | psql -h destinationHost -p 5432 -U dbUser -d destinationDB \
    -c "\copy destinationTable FROM STDIN"
```

Or in Python by running the above command or by using os.pipe and psycpog2's copy_from/to commands.  Unfortunately, neither of these options seem to play too well with concurrency.  This is why I'm looking to do the same thing in go.

So my question - how can I run the above command line command in GO?  Or pipe data to/from different postgres databases?  I'v been experimenting with the following code and haven't had success.  Any tips would be appreciated.

```
import "github.com/go-pg/pg"

//connect to source and destination db's (successful connection confirmed)

r, w := io.Pipe()

println("start")

_, err := destDB.CopyFrom(r, "COPY destinationTable FROM STDIN")
if err != nil {
    println(err)
}

_, err = srcDB.CopyTo(w, "COPY (SELECT * FROM sourceView) TO STDOUT")
if err != nil {
    println(err)
}

srcDB.Close()
destDB.Close()
```

Comment: It might be faster to use postgres instead of an external language,  eg pg_connect or pg_fdw.

Comment: Above your `CopyFrom` and `CopyTo` must be run concurrently  i don't know how go makes threads but suspect that your code isn't doing that.

Comment: It would be faster to use postgres.  Unfortunately, I can't (with the current setup) select data from one database into another.  Hence the need for an external language.  Further, the end goal is to move 30+ tables and would like to do so concurrently.

Comment: I'd run several psql commands concurrently (one for a table) in a bash script. Or would look into existing tools for replication: https://severalnines.com/database-blog/how-replicate-postgresql-data-remote-sites

Answer (score 2):

The reader and writer should be in different goroutines and the write side of the pipe should be closed when done to prevent the read side from hanging. See the following for a starting point:

```
    r, w := io.Pipe()

    writer := make(chan error)
    go func() {
        defer w.Close()
        _, err := src.CopyTo(w, `COPY (SELECT * FROM sourceView) TO STDOUT`)
        writer <- err
    }()

    reader := make(chan error)
    go func() {
        _, err := dest.CopyFrom(r, "COPY destinationTable FROM STDIN")
        reader <- err
    }()

    errWriter := <-writer
    if errWriter != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Writer (CopyTo) error: %v", errWriter)
    }

    errReader := <-reader
    if errReader != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Reader (CopyFrom) error: %v", errReader)
    }

    if errWriter == nil && errReader == nil {
        fmt.Println("All done - no errors")
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  This was exactly what I needed.